# Mercurial: "hg push" to smb share does not work

Tags: mercurial, push, share, smb

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and Mercurial 3.7.3. Our repository is accessible only as an SMB share. I cloned the share to a folder in my home folder (I simplified the names a bit):

```
> hg clone "/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=xyz.com,share=abc$/Repo" Repo
```

My problem is that I can do anything (pull, commit etc.) but push:

```
> hg push -v
pushing to /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=xyz.com,share=abc$/Repo
searching for changes
2 changesets found
uncompressed size of bundle content:
     876 (changelog)
     724 (manifests)
     586  a.txt
    2869  b.txt
   34900  c.rpm
   37325  d.rpm
abort: Operation not supported: '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=xyz.com,share=abc$/Repo/.hg/store/journal'
```

If I use sudo:

```
> sudo hg push -v
[sudo] password for kol: 
pushing to /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=xyz.com,share=abc$/Repo
abort: repository /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=xyz.com,share=abc$/Repo not found!
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

**UPDATE**

I tried the same in Windows 7, and `hg push` worked.

**UPDATE 2**

The SMB share is on a Windows machine.

The output of `hg push` on Ubuntu with the `--debug` option (the commit I tried to push is different than the above):

```
> hg push -v --debug
pushing to /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=xyz.com,share=abc$/Repo
query 1; heads
searching for changes
all remote heads known locally
listing keys for "phases"
checking for updated bookmarks
listing keys for "bookmarks"
listing keys for "bookmarks"
1 changesets found
list of changesets:
9ce3f6fbf7217a7eea79cf21ccbb2d7fc851cbd3
bundle2-output-bundle: "HG20", 4 parts total
bundle2-output-part: "replycaps" 155 bytes payload
bundle2-output-part: "check:heads" streamed payload
bundle2-output-part: "changegroup" (params: 1 mandatory) streamed payload
bundle2-output-part: "pushkey" (params: 4 mandatory) empty payload
abort: Operation not supported: '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=xyz.com,share=abc$/Repo/.hg/store/journal'
```

Comment: On which system (Linux / Windows etc.) does the SMB server run?

Comment: Also, can you try if adding `--debug` as an argument gives useful information? Does `dmesg` show anything interesting while you try the push? Running `dmesg | tail -f` could be helpful to see what's happening.

Comment: @ManuelJacob Please see my 2nd update.

Comment: @ManuelJacob There is nothing interesting in `dmesg` output.

Comment: @kol what about mounting samba share to ypur local file system and working with it afterwards? Then Mercurial will deal with it like with standard file system.

Comment: @kol The mountpoint is strange... What if you mount your smb fileshare via an other tool, as `cifs-utils`?

Comment: I had the same problem and followed @Vincent 's advice. I can push with cifs where I could not with gvsd. I had to add a line to /etc/fstab in order to cifs mount as non-root with `user` option and also to specify my `username` for the samba share.  (there are security issues, I am content to enter my password every time I mount, alternatives include a credentials file, see mount.cifs doc for details)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, this seems to not work with GVFS-mounted directories. CIFS works, though. So, to push to the remote repository, mount it via CIFS.

`sudo mount -t cifs -o user=your_remote_username,domain=your_remote_domain,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) "//remote.server.com/path/to/remote/directory" /media/your_user/smb-mount`

Make sure to set your remote (SMB) username and domain. Also, in case the server sends ownership information for the files, it might be required to add the `forceuid,forcegid` options. For a full description of the command, see [Mount cifs Network Drive: write permissions and chown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68081/39126).

Answer (score 0):

Please please please do not use network filesystems for any version control system. Network filesystems violate some of the consistency guarantees that most version control systems depend on - what you're seeing with the journal file is almost certainly a side effect of that.

Instead, can you run an http hg server on the same machine? That'll *significantly* reduce your risk of data loss.